How to know the database where my procedure was originally called from
I am developing a stored procedure and I would like to know from where it was originally called,  by that I mean, in which database I was when I called my procedure.
I would like to achieve this without a parameter if at all possible.
I am aware of procedure with default parameters although I could not make db_name() as a default parameter, otherwise that would have been the solution.
I am also aware of function as default parameter value although maybe I could get it done that way somehow?
What I got at the moment is via a parameter but it is a bit lame.
select @@SERVERNAME
use master
go

create or alter procedure whereami 
    @origin sysname = null
as
begin
    print @origin

    select [inside the procedure] = @origin
end
go

use [database one]
select db_name()

declare @a sysname = db_name()

use [database two]
select db_name()

exec master.dbo.whereami @origin = @a



For the procedure, the actual database is the one the procedure is in. So you have to go with your lame solution. What do you actually want to achieve? Why do you care where someone is when calling the procedure

You can use sys.dm_exec_sessions to get this info.
SELECT
  d.name AS ConnectingDatabaseName
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
LEFT JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = ISNULL(NULLIF(s.authenticating_database_id, 0), s.database_id)
WHERE s.session_id = @@SPID;

db<>fiddle

This code will return the name of the database where you're executing the procedure.
declare @CalledFromDB sysname;

select @CalledFromDB = databases.name
  from sys.dm_tran_locks
  join sys.databases
    on databases.database_id = dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id
 where dm_tran_locks.resource_type = N'DATABASE'
   and dm_tran_locks.request_session_id = @@SPID
   and dm_tran_locks.request_mode = N'S'
   and dm_tran_locks.request_status = N'GRANT'
   and dm_tran_locks.request_owner_type = N'SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE'
   and dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id <> DB_ID();

select @CalledFromDB = coalesce(@CalledFromDB, db_name());


What a long-winded way of finding out the database. Also doesn't work when in master or tempdb see https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233327&seqNum=3

Depending on what you are trying to do then an undocumented but well known approach is to give it the sp_ prefix and mark it as a system object.
(The sp_ prefix is reserved by Microsoft though so does have the risk of clashing with future object names as well as the risk of the sp_ms_marksystemobject approach being removed in some future version)
e.g.
USE master 

GO

create or alter procedure sp_whereami 
as
    select db_name()

GO

EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'sp_whereami' 

GO

USE tempdb 

EXEC sp_whereami /*tempdb*/

